# How do you turn on the underlined characters in menus for keyboard shortcuts in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-navigation

In Windows XP, there is an option (maybe in display effects? I don't remember at the moment) to hide underlines in menus. This allows you to see the underlined characters in the application menus all the time. The default is hiding the underlines. This means you cannot see which character is underlined in the menu until you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> (Firefox excepted).

Is there an option for this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Navigate to **Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center**
- Click **Make the keyboard easier to use**
- Click **Make it easier to use keyboard shortcuts**
- Check **Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys**
- Click OK